# How to write a better SQL for this scenario

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called "**DEVICE**" which contains these columns:

```
------------------------------------------
SN | User_ID |  State    | ... 
------------------------------------------
1 |  1001   | deployed  | ...
2 |  1001   | deploying | ...
3 |  1002   | inventory | ...
4 |  1003   | deploying | ...
5 |  1001   | deploying | ...
6 |  1002   | synced    | ...
7 |  1002   | synced    | ...
8 |  1010   | synced    | ...
9 |  1008   | unsynced  | ...
---------------------------------------
```

As you can see, this table lists all the devices, which are belong to different user by their user_id. Also for all these devices, their state is one of these 5 types:

```
"inventory", 
"deployed", 
"deploying", 
"synced"
"unsynced".
```

I need a SQL Query that returns back the user_id that holds the maximum devices of each individual State. For example, for the above set of data in the first table, the return would be:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
User_ID     |    State    |   Maximum 
-----------------------------------------------------------
1001        |    deployed |     1 
1001        |    deploying|     2
1002        |    inventory|     1
1002        |    synced   |     2 
1008        |    unsynced |     1 
------------------------------------------------------------
```

The SQL I have created so far is like this:

```
SELECT 
    STATE, ACCOUNT, CNT 
from 
( select account_id as ACCOUNT, state as STATE, count(*) as CNT 
  from DEVICE group by account_id, state ) T1
where  
    ( STATE, CNT ) 
IN 
    ( select STATE, MAX(CNT) 
from 
( select account_id as ACCOUNT, state as STATE, count(*) as CNT 
   from DEVICE group by account_id, state ) T2 
Group by STATE
);
```

which is so ugly. Is there a better way to do that ?

Thanks,

Jack

Comment: What is your MySQL server version ? Do `Select Version()` and report the result pls.

Comment: @user3595231, you have received a few answers. Please feel free to mark one of the answers accepted if it suits your needs and put closure to your question.

Comment: My SQL version is "10.1.23-MariaDB".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an intermediate summary table or a view like so:

```
drop table if exists device_summary;

create table device_summary as
    select user_id, state, count(*) as counter
    from device
    group by user_id, state;
```

Then, you can run a query like so to get your desired results:

```
select d.*
from device_summary d
inner join (
    select state, max(counter) as maxcounter
    from device_summary
    group by state
) d1 on d.state = d1.state and d.counter = d1.maxcounter;
```

Example: https://rextester.com/ZMZH93648

Comment: Thanks all the for the helps. I guess this question is DB and its version related. In my MySQL DB, Zedfoxus's solution works ok, and I was able to get the correct answer.  Thanks for the tips

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `ROW_NUMBER` analytical function as follows:

```
SELECT
    B.USER_ID,
    B.STATE,
    B.CNT
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                PARTITION BY A.STATE
                ORDER BY
                    A.CNT DESC
            ) AS RN,
            A.USER_ID,
            A.STATE,
            A.CNT
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    USER_ID,
                    STATE,
                    COUNT(1) CNT
                FROM
                    DEVICE
                GROUP BY
                    USER_ID,
                    STATE
            ) A
    ) B
WHERE
    B.RN = 1
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=659d9af742a9c64bdf932cf79faf1c52)

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT User_ID, State, count(*) AS Maximum
FROM DEVICE
GROUP BY User_ID, State
ORDER BY User_ID, State
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions, but only need one level of subquery is needed:

```
SELECT USER_ID, STATE, CNT
FROM (SELECT USER_ID, STATE, COUNT(*) as CNT,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY state ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM DEVICE
      GROUP BY USER_ID, STATE
     ) us
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Note:  If there are ties, this returns an arbitrary user.  If you want all of them, use `RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Note:  Window functions are only available in MySQL starting with version 8.